# Populating a textboxlist

Tags: c#, list, textbox

How to populate

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
```

Is it possible to populate to textBoxList with 5 textboxes and the text the boxes contain say

```
textBox1.Text
textBox2.Text
textBox3.Text
textBox4.Text
textBox5.Text
```

and then I'm planning to populate this like

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
 {   //x is a string collection
    x[i]=textBox[i].Text= // some action
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is "is it possible"?  Answer:  Yes, it is.

How?  Well, you need to add your textboxes to your List before you can reference them:

```
textBoxList.AddRange( { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 } );
```

OR

```
textBoxList.Add(textBox1);
textBoxList.Add(textBox2);
textBoxList.Add(textBox3);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using list, your can use this syntax

```
List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    textBoxList.Add(new TextBox { Text = "text box no.:" + i.ToString() });
```